Customising Results with AWS DLT
Although I'm aware that I can find a full list of results for tests ran by AWS DLT in the linked s3, the results aren't entirely human readable. Can we process these results to make them more human readable? If so, what is the best way to do this? Or is there a way to customise Taurus to output a different result format? If so, how is that done with regards to my DLT cloud formation template?
So far I've just been grabbing shots of the results on the cloudfront, but this isn't automated and gets more cumbersome as my tests expand in size.
I've also had a look at using some JMeter Plugins to do this, are there any that anyone would recommend?
